# jquery ui: Is there a way to distinguish a 'real' event from an api call?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using `tabs` from jquery ui where a select-callback is included, working as expected. At one point of the script I need to do a select-method call that also triggers the callback which is not wanted at that point.

What I am looking for is some difference in the event-parameter of the callback which could be used in an if-clause to prevent the contents from the callback to be executed..

I tried `stopPropagating`, but then the default tab functions are not executed either (the classes are not reset)

I hope someone understands what I am looking for  :)

thanks in advance

Comment: not so good solution: Before triggering the select-event set some variable and then use that variable to distinguish.

Comment: I would have liked to to not use an extra var, but that's the way I implemented it now anyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To distinguish a real event from a programmatically generated one you should check for [event.originalEvent](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) wich is undefined if the event is generated programmatically

for example:

```
<button id='my'>Click me</button>
<button id='my2'>Click the other</button>

$('#my2').click(function(){
    $('#my').click();
});

$('#my').click(function(event){
    if (event.originalEvent === undefined){
        alert('computer');
    }else{
        alert('human');        
    }
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uqNHd/

Comment: That's the solution I was looking for. Unforturnately the jquery-ui.tabs (v1.8.16) doesn't pass the originalEvent  :/

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5043

thanks!